# Redirect to one of multiple sites on the server

Tags: redirects, dns, mamp

I hope this is the right place to post this issue, serverfault seemed wrong to me...

Say I have a machine running MAMP.
This machines IP is managed in a account from dyn.com to a specific domain, say `myadress.com`.
In htdocs there is currently only one folder, holding an owncloud system.
Now I thought I could simply add a little homepage by adding a second folder and registred a second domain `mysecondadress.com`, in dyn-account.

But now, instead of setting the IP of `myadress.com` to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/owncloud`
and the IP of the homepage `mysecondadress.com` to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/homepage`,
I was only able to set the IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

So my next idea was, that there has to be a way to redirect, depending on the requested domain.
So that `myadress.com` would be redirected to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/owncloud`
and `mysecondadress.com` would be redirected to `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/homepage`.

To achieve this I found some information about "WebHop", 301-redirects, using .htaccess or even virtual hosts. But the described usage everytime was a different one than my situation. Now I am totally confused what would fit my case or if thats just impossible, the way I thought of it.

As I looked into WebHop it seemed, that I would need 3 domains, say `master.com`, `cloud.com` and `homepage.com`, where the two latter would redirect to `master.com/owncloud` or `master.com/homepage`, but I wasn't able to get this to work.

Was that a wrong approach or did I do something else wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can still accomplish this with 2 domains, like this:

- domainA.com will open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/owncloud
- domainB.com will open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/homepage

For this, you point both domains to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP and then configure your web server to support 2 different vhosts and point each configuration to use webroot of where owncloud and homepage folders are. No redirection is necessary here.

Comment: Okay, thank you - so I will have a deeper look into virtual hosts. Does "Server" in that case mean my MAMP or the actual machine it's running on?

Comment: MAMP. Have a look at this page: http://sawmac.com/mamp/virtual/